# How to get entries in SQL with columns different values

Tags: sql

I have a use case where i have a table such as:

```
key  | attribute |
key1 | x | 
key1 | y |
key2 | z |
key2 | z |
```

Is there a way i can find all keys that have more than one unique attribute  in this query? For this example, i would want to only return key1 since it has attribute x and y and x and y are different, where key 2 only has one attribute that is unique.

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Just use `group by` and `having`:

```
select key
from t
group by key
having min(attribute) <> max(attribute);
```

If you want the key/attribute pairs in detail, then I would recommend `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.key = t.key and t2.attribute <> t.attribute
             );
```